# SQL scripts in Dockerfile is skipped to run if I attach the deployment to a persistent volume

Tags: sql-server, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I create a new image base on the "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server" image.
Then I have a script to create a new database with some tables with seeded data within the Dockerfile.

```js
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
USER root

# CreateDb
COPY ./CreateDatabaseSchema.sql ./opt/scripts/

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=true
ENV MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=myP@ssword#1

# Create database
RUN /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & sleep 60; /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P ${MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD} -d master -i /opt/scripts/CreateDatabaseSchema.sql
```

I can see the database created by my script if I don't attach it to a persistent volume, and DO NOT see the new database if I attach it to a persistent volume. I check the log and don't see any error. Looks like the system skip to process that file. What is the problem that might cause the environment to skip processing the SQL script whci defined in Dockerfile?

thanks,

Austin

Comment: The `RUN` command is probably running fine, but the Kubernetes volume mount will hide the content in the image and replace it with the (initially empty) volume content.  The official database images generally work around this with a complex `ENTRYPOINT` script that populates the database on first startup.

Comment: @DavidMaze, I think your idea leads in the right direction but I do not have any idea how to solve this problem yet.

Comment: I start my project by copying the idea from this post https://dotnetthoughts.net/initialize-mssql-in-docker-container/ However, the persistent volume causes some weird problems that I don't know to fix it yet.

Comment: Note that the `docker run` command in that post doesn't actually mount any persistent storage.  :-/

Comment: What's with `USER root`? The SQL Server images on Docker hub are designed to execute with `USER mssql`.

Comment: Have you read through the official Microsoft docs yet? e.g.: [Configure and customize SQL Server Docker containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-configure) which in turn links to a demo container setup at [mssql-node-docker-demo-app](https://github.com/twright-msft/mssql-node-docker-demo-app).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, the only way to run this image in minikuke is runing as root. sqlservr: Unable to open /var/opt/mssql/.system/instance_id: File: pal.cpp:566 [Status: 0xC0000022 Access Denied errno = 0xD(13) Permission denied]
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: PAL initialization failed. Error: 101

Comment: @DavidMaze, You are correct. Using persistent volume when I deploy this image in min minikube

Comment: Hacking the container to use the `root` account creates a bunch of security issues. You should spend some time auditing and correcting the file system permissions on the linked volume instead.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning ,  do you have any link to show how to do that with non Root user?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using persistent volume is all the data in that directory is replaced by the base image. I need to learn how to create the database after volume mounts

```yaml
volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /var/opt/mssql
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile. Both can work together.

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  mysqlserver:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - make/my/db/persistent:/var/opt/mssql
```

Then you can run it with:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up
```

Have fun